# Redirecting with parameters to a controller in Laravel and picking up the parameters in the second controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I am looking to redirect with parameters to a controller in Laravel and picking up the parameters in the second controller.

I am set up in the first controller as per the docs, link below.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

**The Redirect**

```
  return redirect()->action(
    'quote', ['enquiry' =>  $request->final_enquiry_id]
);
```

**The Route**

```
Route::post('/quote', [
    'as' => 'quote',
    'uses' => 'Quote_Controller@quote'
]);
```

**The second controller**

```
  public function quote(Request $request)
  {
    echo $enquiry;
```

However this currently returns undefined variable.

Is this the best way to do this and if so where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second controller should be as:

```
public function quote($enquiry, Request $request)
{
  echo $enquiry;
```

And your route should be as:

```
Route::post('/quote/{enquiry}', [
  'as' => 'quote',
  'uses' => 'Quote_Controller@quote'
]);
```

Or if want your `enquiry` param to be optional then you can do it as:

```
public function quote($enquiry = null, Request $request)
{
  echo $enquiry;
```

And your route should be as:

```
Route::post('/quote/{enquiry?}', [
  'as' => 'quote',
  'uses' => 'Quote_Controller@quote'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you this does work, for security and access reasons I decided to pass the data through a session.